# How to convert a time that is input in h:mm format to hh:mm format?

Tags: java, date, time-format, timeofday

From a time input in format 5:00 to 05:00!

in `arr[1]` there is "5:00" <--string format

```java
 DateTimeFormatter time=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
 LocalTime arr1 = LocalTime.parse((CharSequence) time.parse(arr[1]));
```

Comment: Interesting error. You are trying to call two different `parse` methods, first `time.parse()`, then `LocalTime.parse()`. You need only one of them. I’d go for `LocalTime.parse()`.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

```
  @Test
  void localTimeFormatTest() {
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("5:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm"));
    
    String result = time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
    
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("05:00");
  }
```

Comment: Rather than using the second formatter you also just do `time.toString()`. Could be considered dirty, though.